# EV3 cannot follow a straight line LeJOS Java

Tags: java, lego-mindstorms, lejos-nxj

I try to let the robot follow a straight line for about 2 metres, using the method:

```
movePilot.travel(2000)
```

but when doing so, the robot seems to be biased and is slightly going to the right side. Is there any possibility to adjust this?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost definitely a hardware problem - specifically an unbalanced design, a wheel that needs to be pushed all the way in, etc. Any difference in weight or design between the two sides can cause this.

Comment: Yes i assumed something like this. Is there any possibility to adjust the velocity of each wheel manually?

Comment: I'm sure there is. I haven't used lejos, but in the EV3 programming software, you can set a very tiny turn instead of going straight to offset the problem.

Comment: Also see http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/6902/3498. I would use sensor feedback to help compensate for any mechanical problems. For example, it is common to use a gyro sensor for this.